WPforGraphQL for ACF plugin upgrade leading to build errors
JAMStack frontend not building upon upgrade to new version of WPGraphQL for ACF plugin.
Working on a JAMStack framework using a Gatsby.js frontend site that queries a headless WordPress CMS via GraphQL.
I need to upgrade plugin WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields version 0.4.1 to WPGraphQL for ACF version 2.2.0.
After switching to the new version of the plugin, I encounter an error when running the gatsby develop command to run the site locally:
ERROR UNKNOWN

gatsby-source-wordpress (undefined) location: line 705, column: 5  
Syntax Error: Expected Name, found }

Error path: undefined

If you haven't already, try adding define( 'GRAPHQL_DEBUG', true ); to your wp-config.php for more detailed error messages.

ERROR #gatsby-source-wordpress_111002 PLUGIN

gatsby-source-wordpress Error occurred while fetching nodes of the "Comment" type.

Side note: 'GRAPHQL_DEBUG' is already set to true.
The error message above suggests an issue with the schema.
I previously thought that the issue might lie within the query strings in the Gatsby project. For the purpose of testing this issue, I've set up a bare-bones Gatsby.js project - which doesn't contain any GraphQL queries, only a configured gatsby-source-wordpress plugin that points to the same WP site. Here is the code in gatsby-config.js:
/**

* @type  {import('gatsby').GatsbyConfig}

*/
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {

siteMetadata: {

title: `My Gatsby Site`,

siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL,

},

plugins: [

'gatsby-plugin-image',

{

resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',

options: {

url: process.env.WORDPRESS_SOURCE_URL,

schema: {

//DO NOT CHANGE FROM 50

perPage: 50,

//30 minute timeout

timeout: 1800000,

// DO NOT CHANGE FROM 30

requestConcurrency: 30,

typePrefix: `Wp`,

},

},

},

'gatsby-plugin-sharp',

'gatsby-transformer-sharp',

],

};

I'm still getting the same error message. Any ideas on what could be causing this?
